# How to make a like button for UIWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, button, core-data, uiwebview

I'm building a reader-anime app in iOS using swift.

I use UIWebView to display the URL that linked to the anime which people want to read.
I have a FavoriteView (Using TableView)that display the anime that people favorite in TableViewCell.
When people is reading in UIWebView, I want to make a "Like Button" on the navigation bar.

In which, people can press into that "Like Button" and I want to do something to save that click event (or the URL that is being displayed in the WebView, I'm not sure)to store it like an object ( can I do that ? :( ), then I want to pass it in to FavoriteView to display it in the Cell of FavoriteView.

Someone suggests me store that click event ( like an object  ) by coredata but I can not imagine what it is.

Comment: I don't understand : do you want to store the click event or do you want to store the url of the website ? I mean, what is going to be displayed on your table view ?

Comment: thanks for reply. I think I exactly want to store the url of the website , then I want to pass that URL (in the WebView) to the cell of the HistoryView to display what people read in the past, please help me if you can , thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let's sum up.

You have a `UIWebView` embedded in a `UINavigationController`.
What you want to do, is to add a button in the navigation bar, so a user can store the URLs of some websites he/she wants to keep a track of. If a user presses this button, then the URL of the current website is stored within you app and is displayed on a `UITableView` that you call `FavoriteView`.

**I'll suppose that your `FavoriteView` and your web view are managed by the same controller** If it's not the case, then change the code accordingly to your structure.

If you only need to store URLs, then you can use `NSUserDefaults` which is much easier to manipulate than `Core Data` ( as you seem to begin with iOS development, it might be better to start this way ).

Your controller should look like that :

```
class ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
{
   let favoriteView = UITableView()
   let urlArray = Array<NSURL>()
   let webView = UIWebView()

   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Initialise your views
   }

   // Etc... ( rest of your code )
}
```

You must add the following code to your `ViewController` ( unless the structure of your code is different, then, you should adapt the answer to your current configuration ).

So first, add a button to your `UINavigationBar` like that :

```
let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Add, target: self, action: #selector(addButtonTapped))
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton
```

Then, you can implement the `addButtonTapped` method that will be called when your button is tapped :

```
func addButtonTapped()
{
    // We first check that the webView actually has a URL, otherwise we return
    guard let url = self.webView.request?.URL
        else {return}

    // Then we store this URL is NSUserDefaults
    // As we will have other URLs to store, it's interesting to store an array of URLs in NSUserDefaults
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    // We first check if the array already exists in NSUserDefaults
    // If it is the case, we use the existing one, if not, we use a new one
    if let existingUrlArray = defaults.objectForKey("keyUrlArray") as? Array<NSURL>
    {
        self.urlArray = existingUrlArray
    }

    self.urlArray.append(url)
    defaults.setObject(self.urlArray, forKey: "keyUrlArray")
    self.favoriteView.reloadData
}
```

Finally, you can display the stored URLs in your `FavoriteView` which is a `UITableView`. The controller that manages your `FavoriteView` has to implemented the `UITableViewDelegate` methods, this way :

```
// Call this method in viewDidLoad() so your UITableView is initialised
func initialiseFavoriteView()
{
    self.favoriteView.delegate = self
    self.favoriteView.dataSource = self
    self.favoriteView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier")

    self.loadFavoritesAndUpdateTableView()
}

// This method fetches the favorites url from NSUserDefaults and store them into self.urlArray which contains the data of your UITableView
func loadFavoritesAndUpdateTableView()
{
    if let urlArrayCheck = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("keyUrlArray") as? Array<NSURL>
    {
        self.urlArray = urlArrayCheck
    }

    self.favoriteView.reloadData()
}

// MARK: UITableViewDelegate methods
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let url = self.urlArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = url.absoluteString

    return cell
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.urlArray.count
}
```

And finally, you want to load the selected URL when you select a cell of your favorite view, so implement this `UITableViewDelegate`'s method :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    let url = self.urlArray[indexPath.row]
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    self.webView.loadRequest(request)
}
```

I repeat it one again : you have to adapt that to your code, I guess your `UIWebView` and your `UITableView` are not managed by the same controller for instance.

Comment: I want to tell you that I'm deploying your idea and it seems successful, thanks you so much for helping me <3 <3 <3 
thanks you

Comment: I'm not use the storyboard. I use .xib file . 
my UIWebView and UITableView are managed by two different Controller, so I'm still can not find the way to : pass data (those URL) that is stored in the UIWebView to the UITableView. I think a lot but I'm still not understand how to do that . When you have free time please help me. Thanks you

Comment: Well, have an array called `favoritesUrls` in the controller that manages your `UITableView`. In the `viewDidLoad` method of this controller, fetch the data from `NSUserDefaults` : `self.favoritesUrls = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults.objectForKey("keyUrlArray")`, and use this array as the data source of your table view ( so basically, replace `urlArray` by `favoritesUrls` is the `UITableViewDelegate` methods I indicate in the code

Answer (score 0):

Easier way of doing this:

```
let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Add, target: self, action: #selector(addFavorite))
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton
```

Then create an array called `favorites`.

Then:

```
func addFavorite() {
    favorites.append(theFavorite)
}
```

To save:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(favorites, forKey: "favorites")
```

To get:

```
if let f = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("favorties") {
    favorites = f as! [\*The type of favorites e.g. String or Int*\]
}
```

Comment: thanks you so much for reading the topic and helping me . I will try your method . Thanks you !!!!!!!!!!